# Insert access denied message for anonymous users of Drupal site

Tags: drupal, access-control

I have a members only site where I'm using the Content Access module to restrict access to content for members. Some of my pages are views of the restricted content. The problem is when an anonymous user looks at the view they just get a blank page. Would it be possible to insert a message saying "Access Denied" or to redirect them (and not the members) to a membership page?

I don't want to restrict the view because I want to show anonymous users the page is there, but just not give them access - it is an incentive to join!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for users of a site that I maintain, the clients wanted to still show the content in the menu and search results etc, and provide links to login/register etc when viewing the restricted node

I used the http://drupal.org/project/restricted_content module. This module lets you customise a message to display to end users.

For an example see http://www.eyeopener.co.nz/tutorials/win-uoa-optometry-ball-tickets-question1

For views I would recommend providing a short teaser to the end user, and when they click through to the node, ask them to login/register

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I forgot to mention I'm using Drupal 7, and unfortunately, I see there is no Drupal 7 release for the restricted content module. For the views teaser, is it possible to just show this for anonymous users? If this is possible I think it would solve my problem.